# Show complex solutions exist

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let A be a complex number and B a real number. Show that the equation 
$\,\lvert z^2\rvert+ \mathrm{Re}\, (Az) + B = 0\,$ has a solution iff $\,\lvert A^2\rvert \geq 4B$. If this is so, show that the solution set is a circle or a single point.

Well i am trying to do the first part first. So assuming the equation has a solution that would mean $z = x+iy$ satisfies the equation.

I was going to let $A = s+it$ for a complex number, but it is not working out for me. Wrong step?

Comment: You surely meant "a **real** solution", as *any* polynomial equation has a solution in the complex field.

Comment: A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka Exer 1.10?

Comment: @Timbuc Why is it polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
0=\lvert z^2\rvert+ \mathrm{Re}\, (Az) + B =
z\overline{z}+\frac{1}{2}(Az+\overline{Az})+\frac{1}{4}\lvert A\rvert^2-\frac{1}{4}\lvert A\rvert^2+B=\left\lvert z+\frac{1}{2}A\right\rvert^2-\frac{1}{4}\lvert A\rvert^2+B
$$
If $4B>\lvert A\rvert^2>0$, then $\lvert z^2\rvert+ \mathrm{Re}\, (Az) + B=\left\lvert z+\frac{1}{2}A\right\rvert^2-\frac{1}{4}\lvert A\rvert^2+B>0$, and hence no solutions.

If $4B>\lvert A\rvert^2\le 0$, set $C=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\lvert A\rvert^2-4B}$, and our equation is equivalent to
$$
\left\lvert z+\frac{1}{2}A\right\rvert^2=C^2,
$$
and hence equivalent to
$$
\left\lvert z+\frac{1}{2}A\right\rvert=C,
$$
the set of solutions of which is the circle centered at $-A/2$ with radius $C$.

Comment: Everything makes sense in all of these solutions except for one minor detail.   |z^2| =  |z|^2 ?

Comment: Which minor detail?

Comment: I thought you could not carry the exponential through like that with absolute values.

Comment: @dc3rd let $z = x+iy$ and work out $|z^2|$ and $|z|^2$.  you can prove it to yourself.

Comment: Well unless i am missing a last step in the simplification of |z^2| then i am not getting the same answer

Comment: $\lvert z^2\rvert=\lvert x^2-y^2+2xyi\rvert=\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2}=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^2}=x^2+y^2=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2=\lvert z\rvert^2$.

Comment: I made a mistake. I wrote x^2 + y^2. Tganks for clearing that up. Guys like you are what make this place tick. I just hope i can soon be in a position to do the same for others. Im going to work on the rest of this and hopefully it wotks out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track by letting $z = x+iy$ and $A=s+it$.  If substitute this in, we have
$$
x^2+y^2+xs - yt+r = 0
$$
where $r$ is my real number.
Try completing the square for $x$ and $y$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy, A=a+ib$  where $x,y,a,b$ are real

So, we have $x^2+y^2+ax-by+B=0$

$\implies\left(x+\dfrac a2\right)^2+\left(y-\dfrac b2\right)^2=B-\dfrac{a^2+b^2}4$

But $\left(x+\dfrac a2\right)^2+\left(y-\dfrac b2\right)^2\ge0$

Hope you can take it from here